# graphics window not working properly in `kml` package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I started working with the package `kml` to perform longitudinal cluster analysis. The package claims to have an interactive graphics window that lets you explore the clusterings found by `kml`. The window can be opened (according to the docs) by calling the function `choice`.

*But: That window does not open. Instead I get an error:*

> `Error in setGraphicsEventEnv(which, as.environment(list(...))) :`
>    `this graphics device does not support event handling`

---

From the docs `?choice`:

> `At first, choice opens a graphics window (for Linux user, the windows should be explicitly open using x11(type = "Xlib")).`

*Note: I'm under Windows 10, R3.6.3*

---

Minimal example:

```
cld <- generateArtificialLongData(25)
kml(cld,3)
choice(cld)
```

---

- *What am I missing?*
- *How can that graphics window be opened?*

Comment: `x11(type = "Xlib"); choice(cld)`

Comment: @cuttlefish44: Thx, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the instruction of package, it mensions "for Linux user, the windows should be explicitly open using x11(type = "Xlib")". So if you are not Linux user, it properly not work well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add relevant links to back your answer.

Comment: The link for choice function: https://rdrr.io/cran/kml/man/choice.html

Answer (score 0):

Using R version 3.5.2 on Windows, add `x11()` before `choice(cld)`. Note that  `type = "Xlib"` as not an argument of `x11()`

```
cld <- generateArtificialLongData(25)
kml(cld,3)
x11()
choice(cld)
```